# disable side scrolling in mobile

Tags: html, css, responsive

I have added the meta viewport in the header

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

as well as `@media` tags in css but on mobile, I am still able to scroll horizontally. 
[This is what I wanted](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dHLaX.png), webpage not able to side scroll on mobile but [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NGyav.png) is what I currently have.

**Edit** 
This is what happened when the webpage is [zoomed out](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d9gQd.png). Maybe this will help to make the situation clearer.

Comment: `html, body { overflow-x: none; }`

Comment: @NooBskie when I edit the element from the webpage itself there is a warning saying invalid property value

Comment: `html, body { overflow-x: hidden; }` try that

Comment: Have you inspected the DOM to determine which element is causing the overflow?

Comment: @NooBskie it works when I tried it with google's responsive test but if I tried it with an android device it doesn't work. When tested on an ipad it works.